# How to create custom retry logic for aiobotocore?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to upload a lot of files to S3. This cannot be done with the standard AWS CLI because of the translation required between file names on disk and object names in S3.  Indeed may of the objects don't exist at all on disk.

I keep getting an error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (SlowDown) when calling the PutObject operation (reached max retries: 0): Please reduce your request rate
```

It doesn't seem to make a difference wether I use boto3 / botocore / aioboto3 / aiobotocore.  I've tried various configurations of retry logic as described [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/retries.html).  Nothing seems to fix the problem.  That includes all three retry modes and retry counts ranging everything from 0 to 50.

I could add custom retry logic to every method that calls the client but that's going to be a lot of work and feels like the wrong approach.

Is it possible to customize the retry logic used by boto3 or aiobotocore?

Comment: Can you share how you used the Config approach in the doc you linked? It works for me.

Comment: @Brian as noted in the question I've been through many permiatations of that config. I've been through all three retry modes documented, and many variations of retry count (min 0 max 50).  Given the question I don't see what good sharing a handful of those config versions would do.

Comment: I understand that. I asked for it because I use `botocore.config` approach in my own projects and it works for me. I was trying to understand why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Brian yeah I've used it a lot too. Never seen anything like this. But then this is the first time I've tried to PUT 20,000,000+ objects of various sizes.  It's like it's just not backing off enough to satisfy AWS servers. It doesn't matter to me if the request take 10 minutes to complete just as long as it completes.

Comment: Another approach you can try is to split the load among different prefixes. S3 rate limit is applied per prefix so if you can parallelize the PUT requests, you won't get SlowDown responses. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/optimizing-performance.html